# When running http requests in nodejs to test my rest api it stops, why?

Tags: node.js, api, rest, http, request

I have a rest api working perfectly and now instead of manually testing it with postman I have written http requests in order to test CRUD operations. I know for a fact that all the requests are working as they give me status codes of 200.

My problem is when running the tests command line will show it ran through nearly all of them but it will not go beyond some of the GET requests (even though I have the same code for requests of the same type earlier in the code.

When I comment out the GET request where it gets stuck, it runs the requests after that one with no problem.

This is the code I have for my GET requests:

```
var options = {
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 4000,
    path: '/api/services/00001/method/01/args/01'
};
http.get(options, function(res) {
   console.log("Got response: " + res.statusCode+"\nGET argument 01 for user 00001 method 01.\n\n ");
}).on('error', function(e) {
   console.log("Got error: " + e.message);
});
```

Am I missing something that will occasionally get the code to stop running?
Any help is appreciated.

I can add code for my other operations as well if needed(POST, PUT, DELETE).

After running my entire code with nothing commented out, I realized that it also stops in my second delete request, code is as follows:

```
var options = {
   host: 'localhost',
   port: 4000,
   path: '/api/services/00001/method/01',
   method: 'DELETE'
};

http.get(options, function(res) {
  console.log("Got response: " + res.statusCode +"\nDELETE method 01 for user 00001.\n\n ");
}).on('error', function(e) {
  console.log("Got error: " + e.message);
});
```

Comment: Did you try setting `agent: false` in the `options` and/or calling `res.resume()` inside your `http.get()` callback to ignore any response data?

Comment: So by setting agent: false in my get requests it manages to move on to the next one, but when I do that for my delete function I get a status code of 404 (200 is it deleted it correctly). When I dont have the agent set in delete I do get status code 200 but it does not move on to my next request. Also what did you mean exactly res.resume() ? where in my callback function should that be place? Im sorry if it is a very simple question I just started learning node js, thank you in advance

Comment: Place it anywhere in the callback, it's to allow the response data stream to drain if you don't care about the response. Not doing this may hold up connections in the agent's socket pool.

Comment: res.resume() worked in my delete request, Ill be doing some testing throughout the day alternating both, but checking it fast I realized the setting the agent to false in one of my get requests broke it, but didnt affect others. I have done some progress with your help though, thank you very much. Ill be posting another comment later in the day.

Comment: `agent: false` shouldn't break anything. All it does is instruct node to not use the global http agent socket pool, so it always opens up a new socket for the request.

Comment: Managed to get everything working perfectly, thank you, was not sure how to give you rep, but if you post me instructions on how to do that, I will happily follow them. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution could be one or both of:

- Setting `agent: false` in your request `options`. This prevents the request from using the global http agent socket pool, meaning the request will get its own new socket every time. I have seen strange things where requests never start because of node's http agent implementation. The one thing you should be aware of though is your OS user's (the one the process is running under) file descriptor limits. If you do a lot of concurrent requests using `agent: false`, you may need to up that OS limit.
- Use `res.resume()` in your request callback to drain any response data from the server whenever you don't care about it. Doing so may ensure that a socket from the http agent socket pool is available for use by another request.